# SubGit Synchronisation issue: error: svn: E175002: connection refused by server

Tags: git, svn, subgit

I am currently working on configuring a SubGit-instance, which should synchonize with a remote svn-server.

The problem is, that after about revision 150000 which were transformed into git commits, it aborts with following message:

```
error: svn: E175002: connection refused by the server
error: svn: E175002: REPORT request failed on '/svn/!svn/vcc/default'
error: Connection timed out: connect
error: Unexpected error has occured...
```

What could be the reason for this problem? maybe because I only have access to one specific project path in SVN?

Comment: This looks like temporary network problem, you can try to continue translation by running `subgit install` command again. If this doesn't help, write to  
subgit-users@subgit.com

Comment: hi, after trying to install it several times, it seems that is slows down very much. now I have configured that it should start at revision 226838, which is the current revision, but it causes network traffic (about 3MB/s), but the filesystem is not growing that much. is this normal or why doesn't the filesystem get full over the weekend with this traffic?

Comment: Probably you've configured it incorrectly (trunk/branches/tags options), so SubGit downloads a lot of data and skips them because trunk/branches/tags options say "these data are not interesting". Please, write to  
subgit-users@subgit.com or to my personal email (you'll find it in my profile on SO) and attach (if possible) your config file, the output of `svn log -v <URL>` command and the installation log (it should be in .subgit/logs)

Comment: Hi, now I have tried to start transforming at revision 240000, but it seems that it stucks... it hasn't created a .git folder and all the files are only 1KB big... could the problem be that svn is a linux and subgit runs on windows?

Comment: This happens when you specify SVN URL or repository layout (trunk/branches/tags directories) incorrectly in SubGit config. Please send your config file and the output of `svn log -v <URL>` to my e-mail, this should shed some light on that problem.

Comment: Hi, I will send you the logs after checking my config once again. Btw, the repository I want to access has following path: REPO_ROOT/folder1/folder2/trunk,branches,tags,patches,... 
and I have not changed the default configuration because it seems correct... could it be a problem when my user has no rights to any other folder than REPO_ROOT/folder1/folder2/*?

Comment: Hi, I will send you the logs after checking my config once again. Btw, the repository I want to access has following path: REPO_ROOT/folder1/folder2/trunk,branches,tags,patches,... 
and I have not changed the default configuration because it seems correct... could it be a problem when my user has no rights to any other folder than REPO_ROOT/folder1/folder2/*?

Comment: No, this is just "connection timeout" error, if it would be authorization error, the message would be different.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue. It was a network problem for me where my SVN server was shut down. Once the SVN server was restarted, everything was good.